# Direct dynamic conversion to array of different type

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I must be missing something obvious but I don't find a direct way of converting an array of type `Object[]` to an array of type `TE[]` with `TE` only known at runtime.

Here is a working version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestArrays
{
    class Program
    {
        static T Parse<T>(string s)
        {
            T result;

            if (typeof(T).IsArray)
            {
                var TE = typeof(T).GetElementType();
                var rawResult = s.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ChangeType(x, TE, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray();
                result = (T)(object)Array.CreateInstance(TE, rawResult.Length);
                Array.Copy(rawResult, (Array)(object)result, rawResult.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

            return result;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Parse<object>("abc"));
            Console.WriteLine(Parse<string>("abc"));
            Console.WriteLine(Parse<int>("123456"));
            Console.WriteLine(Parse<double>("123.456"));

            Console.WriteLine(Parse<object[]>("a,b,c"));
            Console.WriteLine(Parse<string[]>("a,b,c"));
            Console.WriteLine(Parse<int[]>("123,456,789"));
            Console.WriteLine(Parse<double[]>("123.456,456.789,789.101112"));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to convert `rawResult` which is of type `Object[]` to `TE[]` which is the expected return type.

I understand that a direct conversion is not always possible as the size of the array elements may vary.
But here I'd like to convert to another reference type so it could be possible to be done in-place without having to create a new array and allocate the same quantity of memory.

Moreover the elements can be kept as they are already references of the target `TE` type.

I've seen `Array.ConvertAll` but it would too returns an `Object[]`.

Comment: This is kind of a weird requirement. Have you given careful thought to whether this is really what you want to do? I'd consider using a standard serialization/deserialization format like JSON, and leverage a framework to deal with conversions.

Comment: The concrete use-case is the .NET Core configuration API which returns some `object[]` I want to convert to specific `T[]`. Anyway now I want to know. :)

Comment: So the configuration API returns an `object[]` and you happen to know that in your particular case there should be, say, nothing but `int`s inside that array? That's a very different question, and much easier to solve. Use LINQ `var intArray = objectArray.Cast<int>().ToArray();`

Comment: The caller knows that, not my own generic function `T Get<T>(string configParamPath)` it calls. :)

Comment: The caller can relatively easily call `Get<object[]>().Cast<int>()`. It's straightforward and doesn't require reflection. Or you can make a `GetArray<T>()` helper method that does a pass-through to `Get<object[]>().Cast<T>().ToArray()` internally. Since the framework is already creating an `object[]` you can't avoid allocating another array unless you're willing to return something like an `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Indeed I've added an overload dedicated to arrays/enumerables but it generates a temporary array too. So the idea of Basil is the best so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least we can create a new method for array:

```
static T[] ParseArray<T>(string s)
{
    var result = s.Split(',').Select(x => (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray();
    return result;
}
```

And call this method from `Parse<t>()`:

```
static T Parse<T>(string s)
{
    T result;
    if (typeof(T).IsArray)
    {
        var TE = typeof(T).GetElementType();

        MethodInfo method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("ParseArray", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(TE);
        result = (T)generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { s });
    }
    else
    {
        result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you use reflection, you can call ParseArray with `TE` as a generic argument directly, rather than using hard-coded switch cases.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Good catch!

Comment: @BasilKosovan Thanks for this idea. +1 :)

Comment: Do you need better idea?

Comment: @BasilKosovan Just waiting a little just in case. :)